# MongoDB: Saving Data to Model Correctly

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, body-parser

**Goal**: The user model needs to have associated jobs data for the user. I need to be able to access the jobs data for the user with EJS like so: `<%= user.jobs[0] %>`

Current user model:

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    jobs :[{
    name: String,
    score: String
    }]
});
```

The username and password are working just fine. However I am needing to get the jobs data working. The jobs data is a front end javascript array containing 200 ranked jobs which are specific to the user.

I am able to access the data within this variable like so:

```
$( "#testButton").click(function() {
fetch('/test', {
method: 'POST',
headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
body: JSON.stringify(jobs)
}).then((response) => {
console.log(response)
}).catch((err) => {
console.log(err);
})
```

This gives me data that looks like this...

```
[{ 
name: 'Administrative assistant',
score: -48 },
{ 
name: 'Adult literacy instructor',
score: 28 },
{ 
name: 'Advertising copywriter',
score: 45
}]
```

**My question is... how do I take this data... and get it into the user model correctly? Note: I am using body-parser.**

Example of my POST route...

```
router.post("/register", function(req, res){
  var newUser = new User({username: req.body.username});
  User.register(newUser, req.body.password, function(err, user){
      if(err){
      .... etc.
```

Comment: Where is the div element being referenced?? You should be checking against the position of the div. It's probably only working in the mobile because the div takes up most of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*models/User.js*

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: String,
  password: String,
  jobs: [
    {
      name: String,
      score: String,
    },
  ],
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("user", schema);
```

*index.js*

```
const app = require("express")();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const User = require("./models/User");

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.post("/users", async (req, res) => {
  const user = await User.create({
    username: req.body.username,
    password: req.body.password,
    jobs: req.body.jobs,
  });
  return res.status(201).json({
    message: "Created",
    data: user,
  });
});

mongoose.connect("mongodb://root:toor@0.0.0.0:27017/stackoverflow");
mongoose.connection.on("error", err => console.error(err));
app.listen(3000, () => console.log("Listening on :3000"));
```

Making a `post` request with the data to `/users`:

```
{
    "username": "jon",
    "password": "snow",
    "jobs": [
        {
            "name": "software dev", "score": "10 pts"
        },
        {
            "name": "frontend dev", "score": "8 pts"

        }
    ]
}
```

will return:

```
{
    "message": "Created",
    "data": {
        "_id": "5d86ec91023b9785f2b455bb",
        "username": "jon",
        "password": "snow",
        "jobs": [
            {
                "_id": "5d86ec91023b9785f2b455bd",
                "name": "software dev",
                "score": "10 pts"
            },
            {
                "_id": "5d86ec91023b9785f2b455bc",
                "name": "frontend dev",
                "score": "8 pts"
            }
        ],
        "__v": 0
    }
}
```